# How to give id of every fragment in and use it Tab Fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-studio

I build app that provide custom add and remove tabs from TABFragment. now i want to give id of every tab which i created custom. and get the id of where i am exactly. I also used `tab.getPosition` but it give me where am i exactly. For example i created five page. now when i am 4th tab and then i want to 5th tab id 5th page progress under background. Please give me best suggestion and any regards.Thank you

my Add button code.

```
btNewtab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("New Tabs")
                    .setTabListener(HomeActivity.this));  //Adding new tab

             COUNT_TAB+=1;  //Add tab for counting


            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify the individual tabs by Tag easily. just set the tag for each tab and perform action on your basis. i.e

```
 COUNT_TAB+=1;//put this line before so that you can use it as tag
   actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("New Tabs")
                    .setTabListener(HomeActivity.this).setTag(COUNT_TAB));
```

//If you want to set the selected tab initially different from default  then set true or false to indicate which tab should be selected. you can change the position of the added tab also  by setting the position. Below is the code i.e.

```
 actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB1").setTag("tab1")
  .setTabListener(this),0,false);
 actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB2").setTag("tab2")
  .setTabListener(this),1,true);
 actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB3").setTag("tab3")
  .setTabListener(this),2,false);
```

//To handle the click event of the tabs you have to override the onTabSelected() method 
  i have put some sample code hope it will help you.

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        if (tab.getTag().equals("tab1")) {
            // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the
            // container view.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("myvalues", 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        } else if (tab.getTag().equals("tab2")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "two clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (tab.getTag().equals("tab3")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "three clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. This work for give tag, Now how i can get Tag from tab ? and when i have three tab and my currunt position is 2nd tab and my code need get under third tab progress. how to do it.I hope you understand my engish is not good. Thanks again

Comment: how to initialize tab to get current tab position?

Comment: I have modified the code.please check it.I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Now please suggest me how to i remove permanently fragment tab.When i remove tab and after then create new then previous deleted tab show me again.Please help me about this. Thanks a lot men.